# Finding the minimal path from S to T that visit all vertices

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

So I have a complete and directed graph with weights.
I wish to find the shortest path from S to T that visits all other vertices in the graph at least once.
Another important piece of information I might have negative weights but i don have negative cycles.

I found this problem very close to the salesman problem but soon enough I found out that it won't be of any help. That's because the salesman problem does not define destination vertex.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is NP-hard (or rather, it's the optimization version of an NP-hard problem). You can easily reduce from the Hamiltonian Path problem (try, and if you don't succeed, add your attempt to the question).

Comment: What help regarding the problem do you specifically want? The problem is very close to the traveling salesman problem, and it can be proved that it is NP-hard. For solving the problem exactly, there is a $O(2^n n^2)$ dynamic programming algorithm and theoretically nothing better is known. For practical solving, similar techniques as for traveling salesman problem should work for this problem.

Comment: To reduce this to the traveling salesman problem where S and T are not defined, you can add a large weight for all edges going into S and all edges going out from T.

Comment: Thanks alot Shaull and Laakeri. Laakeri That is a good idea I tried adding new vertices and define them as S and T. I'll try what you suggested. It is probably possible to reduce it from the traveling salesman problem. That was my first guess too